# Add the error value into the pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I would like to create a list and convert it to a DataFrame. I know how to use except and continue method to complete the loop.

The code look likes this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

list = ['A', 'AAPL']
url_balance_sheet = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BALANCE_SHEET&symbol={}&apikey=DEMO'
records = []

for s in list:

try:
    response = requests.get(url_balance_sheet.format(s))
    data = response.json()

    records.append({
    'symbol': data['symbol'],
    'total_asset' : data['annualReports'][1]['totalAssets']

except KeyError:
    continue

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

May I know how to add the error symbol and message on the list, and then I can create a dataframe and display the error?

The result should look like this:

```
    symbol.    total_asset.    Note
0.  A.         5223000
1.  AAPL.                      KeyError
```

Comment: The url balance sheet link returns an empty set with no errors or data.  Can you provide an example of what the balance_sheet link might return for you?

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds 'KeyError' to the 'Note' column at the time of the error

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

lists = ['A', 'AAPL','AAA']
url_balance_sheet = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BALANCE_SHEET&symbol={}&apikey=DEMO'
records = []

for s in lists:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url_balance_sheet.format(s))
        data = response.json()
        records.append({
        'symbol': data['symbol'],
        'total_asset' : data['annualReports'][1]['totalAssets']})
    except KeyError:
        records.append({
            'symbol': s,
            'Note':'KeyError'
        })
        continue

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df
    symbol  total_asset Note
0   A         8541000000    NaN
1   AAPL    365725000000    NaN
2   AAA              NaN    KeyError
```